# How to authenticate Lambda generated mutations when AWS AppSync using Cognito

Tags: aws-appsync

At present AWS AppSync can only subscribe to mutations, and this is the only way to get realtime updates. But if changes are made to the backing data outside of AppSync (like a DynamoDB update from a Lambda function) then how can we notify the clients?

The only solution I can see is to create a mutation with a "Local" resolver and have the Lambda that updates DynamoDB call this mutation. But my problem then is AppSync authentication which is set to Cognito in my case.

I tried granting IAM access to `appsync:GraphQL` in my Lambda role but that didn't work until I changed the auth type in AppSync from Cognito to IAM. But then of course Cognito authentication doesn't work for the web clients.

Does my Lambda function have to authenticate with a username and password through Cognito to be able to fire the mutation? Or is there another way I can notify the clients from Lambda?

Comment: I'm assuming you originally had it set up to using Cognito User Pools for AppSync access.  Have you tried grabbing credentials via a Cognito Federated Identity service associated with your user pool and using an appropriately configured authenticated identity policy and using those credentials for IAM access to AppSync?

Comment: Ahhh. So set the auth type to IAM and then pull the IAM credentials from the Cognito auth when calling AppSync in the client. I'll give that a go and report back.

Comment: @hatboyzero That worked perfectly. Put your comment in as an answer and I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: How do you generate the AppSync mutation in your Lambda function? Can't seem to get my head atound it

Comment: I haven't got back to this since but I was planning on using a mutation with a Local resolver. Clients could then subscribe to that.

Comment: You mention as the only solution you can see, is to let a Lambda function that updates Dynamo DB call a mutation with a "local resolver". How do you make that call? What does it look like?

Comment: The Lambda can 'call' the mutation using the `ApolloClient` just like browser client code can. Amazon recently fixed their client library so it runs outside the browser, you just need to import `isomorphic-fetch`.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I ended up solving it with plain a plain HTTP request, using axios.

Comment: @robbannn I'm trying to do exactly that: plain HTTP request using axios but I'm having a hard time with the aws signature v4. How did you do it?

Comment: @robbannn I'm using IAM and trying to do SigV4. Can you share how you did this please?

Comment: Yes I can, but not right now. Im celebrating Swedish midsummer.

Comment: Of course. Enjoy Swedish midsummer! Let me know...

Comment: Hi again Tom! Can you post a question on SO and then I will answer it. That way more people can find the solution?

Comment: Yes, I will asap. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @robbannn Actually I already made one few days ago. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50957895/manually-sign-appsync-url-to-use-in-lambda-gives-bad-signature-error/50961055

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the AppSync auth type to IAM and grab AWS Credentials via a Cognito Federated Identity service associated with your Cognito User Pool with an appropriately configured authenticated identity policy.  You should then be able to use those credentials for IAM access to AppSync.

Comment: Using AWS Amplify it was super simple. After signing in just call `Auth.currentCredentials()`.

Comment: So you used AWS Amplify in your lambda?

Comment: No - the OP mentioned that in order to grant the lambda permissions to access the AppSync endpoints, they had to change the Auth type for AppSync to IAM instead of Cognito User Pools, but their client was using Cognito User Pools for Auth.  I simply suggested how they needed to go about grabbing IAM credentials from the Cognito Federated Identity service to use for IAM Auth on the client side instead.