# Manually sign AppSync URL to use in Lambda gives bad signature error

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-appsync

In a Lambda, I would like to sign my `AppSync` endpoint with `aws-signature-v4` in order to use it for a mutation.

**The URL generated seems to be ok but it gives me the following error when I try it**:

`{
  "errors" : [ {
    "errorType" : "InvalidSignatureException",
    "message" : "The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details. etc...
  } ]
}`

Here is my lambda function

```js
import { Context, Callback } from 'aws-lambda';
import { GraphQLClient } from 'graphql-request';

const v4 = require('aws-signature-v4');

export async function handle(event: any, context: Context, callback: Callback) {
  context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;

  const url = v4.createPresignedURL(
    'POST',
    'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.appsync-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com',
    '/graphql',
    'appsync',
    'UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD',
    {
      key: 'yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy',
      secret: 'zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz',
      region: 'eu-west-1'
    }
  );

  const mutation = `{
    FAKEviewProduct(title: "Inception") {
      productId
    }
  }`;

  const client = new GraphQLClient(url, {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/graphql',
      action: 'GetDataSource',
      version: '2017-07-25'
    }
  });

  try {
    await client.request(mutation, { productId: 'jfsjfksldjfsdkjfsl' });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    callback(Error());
  }

  callback(null, {});
}
```

I got my `key` and `secret` by creating a new user and `Allowing` him `appsync:GraphQL` action.

**What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: Hi Tom! How did it work out?

Comment: @robbannn It works! I had to add `https://`to the url param in the `axios` call though. Now I'm having a hard time configuring my VPC to have internet in my lambda :'(

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is how I trigger an AppSync mutation using by making a simple HTTP-request, using `axios`.

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const axios = require('axios');

exports.handler = async (event) => {    
    let result.data = await updateDb(event);

    return result.data;
};

function updateDb({ owner, thingName, key }){
    let req = new AWS.HttpRequest('https://xxxxxxxxxxx.appsync-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/graphql', 'eu-central-1');
    req.method = 'POST';
    req.headers.host = 'xxxxxxxxxxx.appsync-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com';
    req.headers['Content-Type'] = 'multipart/form-data';
    req.body = JSON.stringify({
        "query":"mutation ($input: UpdateUsersCamsInput!) { updateUsersCams(input: $input){ latestImage uid name } }",
        "variables": {
            "input": {
                "uid": owner,
                "name": thingName,
                "latestImage": key
            }
        }
    });

    let signer = new AWS.Signers.V4(req, 'appsync', true);
    signer.addAuthorization(AWS.config.credentials, AWS.util.date.getDate());

    return axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: 'https://xxxxxxxxxxx.appsync-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/graphql',
        data: req.body,
        headers: req.headers
    });
}
```

Make sure to give the IAM-role your Lambda function is running as, permissions for `appsync:GraphQL`.

Comment: Thank you. Looks great! I'll try this asap and let you know. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Looks like a nice solution! I've tried it out myself and i'm getting the following error from my lambda. Not sure what's the problem here, maybe you know why this occurs? My Lambda is has `AWSAppSyncInvokeFullAccess` policy attached which should give `appsync:GraphQL`  



`write EPROTO 139686890170176:error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:802:`

@Tom did you try this solution? And did it work for you?

Comment: It does work for me. I just add to remove the `https` from the `new AWS.HttpRequest` param. Your error talks about SSL, maybe that's the problem.

Comment: Thanks mate works like a charm! Like that you pick stuff from the aws-sdk.

Comment: Getting the same error as @MånsDahlström. Not finding much about how to fix it except using Node 6 which I'd rather not do.

Comment: Thanks a lot @robbannn your solution worked like a charm for me

Answer (score 3):

Adding an answer here because I had difficulty getting the accepted answer to work and I found an issue on the [AWS SDK GitHub issues](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/1247#issuecomment-264285589) that said it's not recommended to use the `AWS.Signers.V4` object in production. This is how I got it to work using the popular  [aws4](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws4) npm module that is recommended later on in the issue linked above.

```
const axios = require('axios');
const aws4 = require('aws4');

const query = `
    query Query {
      todos {
        id,
        title
      }
    }`

const sigOptions = {
        method: 'POST',
        host: 'xxxxxxxxxx.appsync-api.eu-west.amazonaws.com',
        region: 'eu-west-1',
        path: 'graphql',
        body: JSON.stringify({
            query
        }),
        service: 'appsync'
    };

const creds = {
    // AWS access tokens
}

axios({
        url: 'https://xxxxxxxxxx.appsync-api.eu-west/graphql',
        method: 'post',
        headers: aws4.sign(sigOptions, creds).headers,
        data: {
            query
        }
    }).then(res => res.data))
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to construct a pre-signed URL to call an AWS AppSync endpoint. Set the authentication mode on the AppSync endpoint to AWS_IAM, grant permissions to your [Lambda execution role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/security.html#aws-iam-authorization), and then follow the steps in the ["Building a JavaScript Client"](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/building-a-client-app-javascript.html) tutorial to invoke a mutation or query.

Comment: I understand but since I only need to do a single mutation in the context of my lambdas, I think it would be overkill and pretty heavy to use a client. Using a signed HTTP request should be faster and lighter don't you think?

Comment: Pre-signed URLs work only if the service has support for them. As far as I know, only Amazon S3 and AWS IoT support pre-signed URLs. AWS AppSync does not support pre-signed URLs at this time. If you don't want to use the AppSync client, you can use any other HTTP client to make the GraphQL invocations. [robbannn's response using Axios](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51000957/137598) is perfect.

Comment: Well thank you very much. Your comment explains 3 days of mistakes and missunderstanding.  Thank you.